# R data.table: evaluating address of an object in parent frame

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to evaluate an expression containing an `address` of an object at a `parent.frame` scope, and am getting weird results:

```
test2 <- function(d) {
  address.current <- address(d)                          # "0x5595b73aedf8"
  address.at.caller <- eval(parse(text="address(df)"))   # "0x5595b73aedf8"
  address.at.caller2 <- do.call(address, args=list("df"), envir=parent.frame())   # problem: "0x5595b6d89de8"
}

test1 <- function(df) {
  test2(df)
}

df <- data.frame(a=1:2)
test1(df)
```

Moreover, if you stop at a breakpoint inside `test2` and re-evaluate the expression for `address.at.caller2` you'd get non-repeating results:

```
Browse[2]> do.call(address, args=list("df"), envir=parent.frame())
[1] "0x5595b8c37d78"
Browse[2]> do.call(address, args=list("df"), envir=parent.frame())
[1] "0x5595b8cc74a8"
Browse[2]> do.call(address, args=list("df"), envir=parent.frame())
[1] "0x5595b8cd1348"
```

This seems to indicate that the result is an address of some temporary object. (Evaluate repeatedly `address(2)` for a different example).

Is something wrong with the expression `do.call(address, args=list("df"), envir=parent.frame())`?

Is there a different explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not really clear what you are trying to do by using `do.call`. When you use it like you did, you gave it a variable ( a string) and you asked it for the address. the thing is that R automatically creates copies when you enter variables into functions. So  when you gave `args = list("df)` what R did was create a copy of the string "df" within the `do.call` frame, and then it gave you the local address before closing the call. You should pass the variable you want to evaluate into the function, or alternatively have it sit on the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.
You don't have to pass input variable really, or operate on the global scope. You can use a more robust alternative to `do.call`, the `eval(as.call(.))`.

```r
test2 <- function(d) {
  address.current <- address(d)
  print(address.current)
  address.at.caller <- eval(parse(text="address(df)"))
  print(address.at.caller)
  address.at.caller2 <- do.call(address, args=list("df"), envir=parent.frame())
  print(address.at.caller2)
  address.at.caller3 = eval.parent(as.call(list(quote(address), as.name("df"))))
  print(address.at.caller3)
}

test1 <- function(df) {
  test2(df)
}

df <- data.frame(a=1:2)
test1(df)
```

```
[1] "0x560d46e33cc0"
[1] "0x560d46e33cc0"
[1] "0x560d46e4a5f8"
[1] "0x560d46e33cc0"
```